# Sync framework unique constraint violation

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-sync-framework

Consider 2 tables, Employee and Location.

Employee

```
EmpId Name LocationId

xxx   XYZ  yyy
xxx   ABC  zzz
```

Location

```
LocationId Location

yyy        India
xxx        USA
```

EmpId and LocationId are are primary key columns of type `uniqueidentifier`. LocationId in Employee table is a foreign key, referring to the Location table. Also, assume that there is a unique constraint on the location column in the Location table.

Step 1: Synchronize between client and server. The data is now updated.

Step 2: Add a new row in the location table with value as 'France' in both server and client. Also, add new rows in the employee table referring to this new row.

Step 3: Synchronize. It will fail as the unique constraint is violated. The 'France' row is present in both client and server with different primary keys, and when the Sync framework tries to insert a new row, the unique constraint prevents it, and the synchronization fails.

I need to overcome this problem by updating the client locationid to the server locationid for the conflicting row. I tried to write code to update it in the `dbapplychangefailed` event, however, the Sync framework locks the conflicting row and I'm unable to access it.

The unique constraint on a non-primary key column is my main problem, and if I can get a solution to that problem, I can implement it in this scenario.

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have different PKs as you say but you're getting a unique constraint violation? what's the actual unique constraint? can you clarify what you mean you can't access the conflicting rows? they should be available in the conflict itself.

Comment: the PK is the locationId column, I have added the unique constraint for the location column.
As I said, I want to update/delete the conflicting row in the client table but the query gets stuck and I get a Timeout exception after a while. I can access the row values using `e.Conflict` but i actually want to update the value in the db, which I'm unable to.

Comment: assuming you're doing a download sync, you can set conflict resolution to Apply on Next Sync, let the sync finish, delete the conflicting row, resync.